# Get List Items that contains spaces

Tags: javascript, app, query, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am creating a SharePoint 2013 hosted app and I have come across a problem.
I am able to submit everything to my list including a text box that say for instance may contain "this is a test". However when I run a query to get these results back I find that my text box only contains "this" for some reason it is ignoring everything after the space.

**This is what I see in the app**

[image: App Text Box]

**This is what I see in the SharePoint List**

[image: What I see in SharePoint List]

My code that I am using to retrieve items from the SharePoint list is:

```
 function getListItems() {
    web = appContextSite.get_web();
    mylist = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Expenses');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ParentID\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + queryparameter1 + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    var collListItem = mylist.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(mylist);
    context.load(collListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, ListItemssuccessHandler),
     Function.createDelegate(this, ListItemserrorHandler)
    );

    function ListItemssuccessHandler() {

        $(".mydiv").empty();
        var listInfo = '';
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

        listInfo += "<table class='table table-hover table-condensed' id='MyTbl'><thead><tr>"
            + "<th>Details</th>"
            + "<th>Code</th>"
            + "<th>Number</th>"


        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

            listInfo += '<td><input type="text" id="detailsInput" name="Details" value=' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + ' size="35" required="required" /></td>'
            + '<td><select id=\'CodeDropdown\'><option value=' + oListItem.get_item('Code') + '>' + oListItem.get_item('Code') + '</select></td>'
            + '<td><input type="number" name="Amount" id="Amount" value=' + oListItem.get_item('Amount') + ' min="0.00" max="9999" step="0.01" size="4" required="required" /></td></tr>';

        }

        listInfo += '</tbody></table>';
        $('.mydiv').html(listInfo);
    }
```

Is there something I am doing wrong when pulling back the data? How do I go about pulling back the full string of text please?

Comment: if you debug, what is the value of oListItem.get_item('Title')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing quotes `""` around the value of textbox.

Use

```
'<td><input type="text" id="detailsInput" name="Details" value="' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '" size="35" required="required" /></td>'
```